# Распределение задачи по докер контейнерам Docker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

у меня есть несколько docker-образов,которые проверяют файл на наличие вирусов. Вот мои контейнеры

```
malice/windows-defender    latest      3f8fd7504140   2 months ago    321MB
malice/sophos              latest      05ad9655a575   23 months ago   987MB
malice/comodo              latest      7ebc32f699df   23 months ago   751MB
malice/avg                 latest      7351100aa928   23 months ago   687MB
malice/clamav              latest      7da4570bddd2   2 years ago     211MB
```

Все они имеет простую команду для проверки файла, например для malice/avg

```
docker run --rm -v /path/to/malware:/malware:ro malice/avg FILE
```

где

```
path/to/malware - директория в которой лежат проверяемые файлы на хостовой машине
```

Как мне сделать так, что бы у меня был кластер,который состоял бы из машин на которых запускались бы все эти образы и файл проверялся всеми этими средствами автоматически ?
Можно ли сделать это в Docker Swarm ?

Comment: Можно уточнить: под кластером понимается несколько физических машин, на котрых запускаются докер-контейнеры?

Comment: нет, все должно запускаться на одной машине

Comment: Нужно как-то запустить набор докеров с командами которые проверяют файл на одной машине

Comment: я прошу прощения, а просто написать sh - файл - не подойдёт как решение? Или нужно запустить докеры параллельно?

Comment: да,нужно чтобы докеры запускались параллельно)

Comment: и еще нужно чтобы можно было регулировать кол-во узлов проверки, как раз docker-swarm предоставляет такую возможность, но пока что я мало в разбираюсь в работе docker swarm. Есть ли возможность мою задачу возложить на docker swarm ?

Comment: Идеально было бы поднять несколько докер контейнеров ( со средствами проверки ) и дать им задачу проверки файла

Comment: а что, если проверку запкскать не через docker run, а через docker start? Много ресурсов сэкономится, если пользоваться уже построенным контейнером

Comment: Это было бы хорошо,да, но как сделать так,чтобы проверка выполнялась параллельно с возможностью расширить кол-во узлов для проверки ? Ну есть вариант такой : слепить из всех моих образов один - и запихнуть его в Docker Swarm. Там можно задать как раз то что нужно - количество узлов для проверки. Но можно ли этого ( объединения в один образ ) избежать ?

Comment: Как я понимаю, docker swarm - это про запуск "стаи докеров". в классике - один докер это база, один - аутентификатор, один - nginx, и еще один - это тот микросервис, котрый вы пилите. И всё это должно "взлетать" по одному нажатию на кнопку, чтобы можно было Ваш микросервис протестировать в окружении. Если прописать кучу независимых докеров, котрые проверяют каждый своим антивирусом - вроде бы, получится то, что Вы хотите. Но сильнее, чем советом - помочь не могу, у меня нет опыта в сварме :-(

Comment: А что значит фраза "Если прописать кучу независимых докеров" ? Где прописать ? Вы про docker-compose ?

Comment: ну с композом я больше опыта поимел. я думал, что любая оркестрация - это примерно как композ

Comment: То есть предложение такое : объединить образы для проверки файла в файле docker-compose и его запустить на кластере ?

Comment: Ну, в принципе - да! То есть, использовать систему оркестрации для одновременного запуска докеров

Comment: А как мне передать параметр : имя файла в docker-compose ? Для запуска сканирования команда принимает имя файла docker run --rm -v /path/to/malware:/malware:ro malice/avg FILE. Я не могу его заранее задать в docker-compose, как туда передать динамический параметр ?

Comment: А через environment не получится? Ключик -e при запуске докер - контейнера...

Comment: попробую сейчас